SqlConnection reports no connection string even though the string is passed and printed to a log
below code, when trying to open a connection to the database returns InvalidOperationException with the message: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
In the ConfigureConnection method I print the passed connection string to my log, and it prints out fine. I am using this line to get the connection string from my XML file and pass it into the DBManager: DBManager.Instance.ConfigureConnection(XmlManager.Instance.GetNode("Resources\\config.xml", "/config/application/db").Attributes.Item(0).Value);
private static DBManager? _instance;
private SqlConnection _connection;
private DataTable? _tableInfo;

private static object _lockObj = new Object();
public static DBManager Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new DBManager();
        }
        return _instance;
    }
}

#region ConfigureConnection
public void ConfigureConnection(string connectionString)
{
    EventLogger.LogEvent($"Connection string received: {connectionString}");
    _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
#endregion

private bool ManageConnection(ConnStatus status)
{
    try
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case ConnStatus.Open:
                _connection.Open();
                return true;
            case ConnStatus.Close:
                _connection.Close();
                return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
    {
        EventLogger.LogEvent(ioe.Message);
        return false;
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        EventLogger.LogEvent($"Error! SqlException: {se.Number}");
        return false;
    }
}

I cannot figure out why is the new SqlConnection() object instantiation not accepting the connection string?

I advise against such Db classes, they can cause several issues since they are making it harder to use the using statement which you should use, to ensure that the connection gets closed as fast as possible. By the way: you don't show how you use it, where do you call ManageConnection? Show also the full stack trace of the exception.

@TimSchmelter As far as i understand, I shouldn't be using the ManageConnection method but, everywhere i need to open and close connection i should go with using statement?

Also, how i call  ManageConnection :
{
    if (ManageConnection(ConnStatus.Open))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}", _connection);
        _tableInfo = GetTableInfo(tableName);
        ManageConnection(ConnStatus.Close);
        return da;
    }
    else
    {
        ManageConnection(ConnStatus.Close);
        return null;
    }
}```

Yes, throw this class to the garbage can and use the using statement wherever you use the connection. If you look at the linked answer in my comment, you'll see that the issue for that was the static connection, which you also have(DBManager). If you use it in a multi threaded context(like ASP.NET), you will have issues. Singletons and ADO.NET also don't play well together, especially because ADO.NET uses connection pooling by default, so maintains the physical connections to the DB.

@TimSchmelter ngl, i would never see that one coming, i had that class as static for ages and all worked good, untill i turned a different class into static. Thanks anyways, I'll make adjustments :D

Which dbms are you trying to connect to?
